# Given a signature with two abstract types, define a subsignature that makes them equal

Tags: module, sml, signature

I have a very large signature with two abstract types:

```
signature GENERAL_FOO_BAR =
sig
  type foo
  type bar
  (* lots of stuff here *)
end
```

I want to declare a subsignature of `GENERAL_FOO_BAR`, where the two abstract types are identified, but none of the following attempts works:

```
signature SPECIAL_FOO_BAR = GENERAL_FOO_BAR
  where type foo = bar

signature SPECIAL_FOO_BAR = GENERAL_FOO_BAR
  sharing type foo = bar
```

It would be very cumbersome to use a dummy type as follows:

```
signature SPECIAL_FOO_BAR =
sig
  type both
  include GENERAL_FOO_BAR
    where type foo = both
    where type bar = both
end
```

Since it forces anyone who wants to implement `SPECIAL_FOO_BAR` to, well, define the dummy type. Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to be so explicit about "subsignatures". Here is a simple example of "subsignatures":

```
signature F =
sig
    type foo
    type bar
end

signature G =
sig
    type foo = int
    type bar = string
end

structure C : G =
struct
    type foo = int
    type bar = string
end

structure D : F = C
```

Comment: My `F` is *very* large, though. I wouldn't want to duplicate it. As a matter of fact, I don't even like `include` much, but here it would save a lot of space.